# Multiple htpasswd user entries

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-web-services, htaccess

Using a Bitnami WordPress instance on AWS and the main issue I'm having is adding multiple users to my htpasswd file and have them authenticate to the site.

Command : 
sudo apache2/bin/htpasswd apps/wordpress_bitnami newuser

where "wordpress_bitnami" is the htpasswd file. It adds the name entry correctly, then I restart, but cant authenticate when I try to log into the site.

Bitnami Doc to add a htpasswd entry, under the section "How to create a password to protect access to apache?"
https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/Apache

Then, to added multiple users, followed the example on this link
http://www.inebraska.com/help/htaccess/htpasswd_ex.html

I have a total of 3 entries. The first entry logs in correctly but the other two don't. I moved the first entry to the second position and same result to see if its a matter of apache not finding the entry, was able to log in with the original entry.  Then I changed the passwords for all three and same result, only the original logs in and not the others.  Strange?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Multiple entries are allowed, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42968134/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  To allow multiple users to access your site via htpasswd the instructions are in the link below.

Section "Letting more than one person in"
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html